# Remove previous line to a match string?

Tags: bash, sed

How I can remove the previous line of a match pattern?

Or

the opposite of:

```
sed -n '/pattern/{g;1!p;};h'
```

Comment: Is `awk` acceptable? If so, add the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Use `tac | sed | tac` (Linux/Solaris) then it's next line after a match pattern :)

Answer (score 4):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk:

```
$ cat file
here is a
a bad line before
a good line
in a file

$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/good/) del[NR-1]; next} !(FNR in del)' file file
here is a
a good line
in a file
```

You can use the above idiom to delete any number of lines before and/or after a given pattern, e.g. to delete the 3 lines before and 2 lines after a given target:

```
$ cat file
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
target
+1
+2
+3
+4
+5
$
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/target/) for (i=-3;i<=2;i++) del[NR+i]; next} !(FNR in del)' file file
-5
-4
+3
+4
+5
```

or to leave the target in place and just delete the lines around it:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/target/) for (i=-3;i<=2;i++) if (i!=0) del[NR+i]; next} !(FNR in del)' file file
-5
-4
target
+3
+4
+5
```

All very clear, trivial, and scalable...

Comment: What is `file file`? Why two times?

Comment: It's a 2 pass approach so it reads the file once to identify the target lines and then a second time to remove them.

Comment: if there any way to get it working if I have "/" symbol inside and variable substitution inside the target?

Comment: @Patlatus Yes. Ask a new question about that.

Comment: Ok, posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69451009/use-awk-or-sed-to-remove-lines-in-xml-file-around-target-search-string-containin

Answer (score 2):

For "relatively complex" navigation around a search expression, [`ed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Commands) might be a good solution (comments are *not* part of the command):

```
ed testfile << EOF
/r.*o/                        # Search the pattern
-1d                           # delete one line above
w                             # write
EOF
```

Here is an example (using `<<<` and `\n` to write as a single line):

```
sh$ cat testfile
john
paul
george
ringo
sh$ ed testfile <<< $'/r.*o/\n-1d\nw'
23
ringo
16
sh$ cat testfile
john
paul
ringo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can revert the file and then delete the line after the matche pattern(which is simple), and then revert the result, here is the code:

```
tail -r|sed '/pattern/{n;d;}'|tail -r
```

Comment: in `zsh` and bash there is no `r` flag for `tail`. I use debian.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/ {f=1} !f&&NR>1 {print p} {p=$0;f=0} END {print p}' file
```

---

A `tac awk` version:

```
tac file | awk '1; /pattern/ {getline}' | tac
```

PS `getline` should normally be avoided since it has many pitfalls, so then this:

```
tac file | awk '!p||NR!=p+1; /pattern/ {p=NR}' | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '$!N;/\n.*pattern/!P;D' file
```

Keep a window of 2 lines and test the second of them for the pattern. If the pattern is present do not print the first line.

Comment: @KanjiViroja I may have missed an edge case please show your test case

Answer (score 0):

This would work but only if line count is more than 1 and pattern is not at the last line.

```
sed -n '/pattern/ { h; b }; 1 { h; b }; ${ H }; x; p' file
```

Better use `awk` instead:

```
awk '!/pattern/ && NR > 1 { print p } { p = $0 } END { if (NR) print p }' file
```

Comment: It does not work if we get a consecutive pattern matched.

Comment: @KanjiViroja Yes consecutive-line matching is possible, but that's no longer part of the original target of the topic. When it comes to that, it is unclear how the OP would want it to behave.